# Virtuoso: view local description of resources with IRIs from remote authority

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

I'm new with RDF and Virtuoso. I've installed Virtuoso 7 on my machine and I have uploaded the N3 file on Virtuoso following the instructions in this tutorial: http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoaderExampleSingle.

A resource in the N3 example has IRI:
http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this.

When I query with SPARQL, I see the results, but if I want to explore the link, the browser doesn't find the URL because it explores the `openlinksw.com` domain.

I would like the browser to redirect to `localhost` to find the resource. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing the IRI `http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this` -- or any other remote IRI -- should not result in a redirect to `localhost`, else you risk entirely breaking the web for yourself.

However, if you fully install the RDF-related modules (particularly the Faceted Browser), you will be able to explore via pages like --

- http://localhost:8890/fct/
- http://localhost:8890/about/html/http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com#this
- http://localhost:8890/describe/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fdataspace%23kidehen%40openlinksw.com%23this

Take a look at the publicly accessible URIBurner instance for how you might expect these to work on your own instance --

- http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/fct/
- http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/html/http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/kidehen@openlinksw.com
- http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/describe/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fdataspace%2Fkidehen%40openlinksw.com%23this